# How can you make custom skills for Fate?

Tags: skills, fate, fate-core

How does creating custom skills in Fate core work? Can you just say "I want this skill" and get away with it or is there some sort of preset rules such as designing stunts and such for the skill before adding it to the game? To be specific, I want to create a skill called *Magical Engineering* as my character will not be knowledgeable about lore or be able to craft most of the things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Fate SRD deals with creating new skills in its [System Toolkit section](https://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/skills). It goes into considerable detail including modifying the basic list by addition or removal of skills and grouping skills into "modes" or "professions".

You might want to define a "restricted access" skill as an [extra](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/extras).

Comment: Are you sure the options in that toolkit are meant for a *player* to apply? It seemed more like they were designed for use by the GM to adjust skills to match the game's intended setting/playstyle.

Comment: The general expectation is that the skill list is determined at the campaign level (GM assembled with player input). That said if the GM is open to someone creating a custom skill, it's not prohibited, tho I'd counsel close examination in case it's broader in scope than the skills already available in the game; you want to avoid someone creating an always-applicable "omni-skill".

Comment: See also Custom Skills from Atomic Robo: https://fate-srd.com/atomic-robo/custom-skills

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, if your entire vision for this skill is "Lore, but it can't do as much", you might want to consider one of the following approaches:

- Take Lore at a low rating, or perhaps don't at all, depending, and a Stunt that gives you +2 to use Lore for things that fall under the auspices of Magical Engineering. It should probably be narrow enough that it's reasonable for a Stunt to boost it under those circumstances.
- Take Lore at the rating you want Magical Engineering to have, and also the Aspect **I'm An Engineer; I Solve *Practical* Problems**. Whenever you're in a situation where it would be useful to know something about magic or history, darn the luck if that ain't one of those conundrums of philosophy.